# Setting tab order programmatically in Delphi

Tags: delphi, edit

I'm trying to create some controls programmatically and it simply doesn't work. I'm posing an example where I try to create 11 Edit components and set tab order to go from first to last.

```
procedure CreateControls;
var
  TabOrder: Integer;
  UniEdit: TEdit;
begin
  TabOrder:= -1;
  for i:= 0 to 10 do
  begin
    Inc(TabOrder);
    UniEdit:= TEdit.Create(Self);
    UniEdit.Parent:= pnlFields;          //panel
    UniEdit.Height:= 20;
    UniEdit.Width:= 30;
    UniEdit.Top:= Top;
    Left:= Left;
    Top:= Top + 23;
    UniEdit.TabStop:= True;
    UniEdit.TabOrder:= TabOrder;
  End;
end;
```

Comment: They are IN the tab order you created them. If you're creating them, why are you tweaking the tab order at all?  They should be ordered already.

Comment: @WarrenP OK. good point. So I removed line involving tabOrder and it still does not work. When I press TAB edit simply lose focus and doesn't move to another control.

Comment: I partially agree with @WarrenP. It is most likely. However, if the form has other controls their `TabOrder` will be less then the order of the created Edits. Probably skafinski wants these edits to be before them?

Comment: This (and asd-tm's imroved version) should work. A couple of questions come to mind. Is pnlFields really a TPanel? Could it be pnlFields has a lot more controls as children that are out of view? Do you catch keystrokes on the form level (KeyPreview) ? Any events that may be ruining your plan? If you do this in design-time, does it make any difference?

Comment: @skafinski Please, do not edit the question in a way that makes it senseless. You have just copied my answer and the community can not see the starting problem now. Please, revert the edit to the previous versions and append a new section to it if you have something to add.

Comment: It seems to me this is a classic XYProblem.  (The question as posed is not the actual problem that the OP thinks it is.)

Comment: Posting fake code doesn't help. Post your [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the corrected code:

```
var
  UniEdit: TEdit;
  i:byte;
begin
  for i:= 0 to 10 do
  begin
    UniEdit:= TEdit.Create(Self);
    UniEdit.Parent:= panel1;          //panel
    UniEdit.Height:= 20;
    UniEdit.Width:= 30;
    UniEdit.Left:= 20;
    UniEdit.Top:= 20+ 23*i;
    UniEdit.TabStop:= True;
    UniEdit.TabOrder:= i;
  end;
end;
```

Otherwise the scope of properties like `Left:= Left;` means that the code refers to `Self.Left:= Self.Left;` that is equal to `TForm1.Left:= TForm1.Left;` but not to `Uniedit.Left` etc.

Comment: You could remove the line `TabOrder:= -1;` entirely, also `TabStop` is already set to `true` in create

Comment: @SebastianProske You are right. I had to remove too much :-) and missed this line.

Comment: @asd-tm I agree. It is useless to Edit control. Howewer TabOrder still doesn't work.

Comment: @skafinski: Please, specify, what do you mean by 'doesn't work'? For me it works fine. The created edits are in sequential tab order. Have you checked the last edit of my answer?